# Deploying Stub Runner Boot Server to PCF

Tags: cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-contract

We are trying to use Stub Runner Boot to have a stub server and stubs available on Nexus (and local repo).

Locally I more or less sorted it out, with the help of other questions I submitted.

But now, I think I will face another problem and I'm stuck again... We are going to deploy the stub server to our PCF for smoke testing.
We can happily say `curl pcf_host/stubs` and it will respond with the list of configured stubs and port numbers.

But the stubs will be running in some port (that we can even make static, configuring the stub server) but I don't think we'll be able to call PCF on a port other than 443 (or perhpas 80), or can we?

Now that I wrote all of this, I'm starting to realise that the problem is more related with PCF than with SCC, and I must say that my knowledge of PCF is even smaller than of SCC.

Would appreciate if someone could help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very good that you asked this question :)

We already solve this problem with Spring Cloud Pipelines. You can read about this more in https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-pipelines/single/spring-cloud-pipelines.html#_3_8_enable_stubs_for_smoke_tests .

To put it briefly, you need to open ports and allow multiple port binding for your app. Also you have to generate routes. We already do that here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-pipelines/blob/master/common/src/main/bash/pipeline-cf.sh#L577

Let me copy the main part of that code over here

```
# FUNCTION: addMultiplePortsSupport {{{
# Adds multiple ports support for Stub Runner Boot
# Uses [PAAS_TEST_SPACE_PREFIX], [ENVIRONMENT] env vars
#
# $1 - Stub Runner name
# $2 - IDs of stubs to be downloaded
# $3 - path to Stub Runner manifest
function addMultiplePortsSupport() {
    local stubRunnerName="${1}"
    local stubrunnerIds="${2}"
    local pathToManifest="${3}"
    local appName
    appName=$(retrieveAppName)
    local hostname
    hostname="$(hostname "${stubRunnerName}" "${ENVIRONMENT}" "${pathToManifest}")"
    hostname="${hostname}-${appName}"
    echo "Hostname for ${stubRunnerName} is ${hostname}"
    local testSpace="${PAAS_TEST_SPACE_PREFIX}-${appName}"
    local domain
    domain="$( getDomain "${hostname}" )"
    echo "Domain for ${stubRunnerName} is ${domain}"
    # APPLICATION_HOSTNAME and APPLICATION_DOMAIN will be used for stub registration. Stub Runner Boot
    # will use this environment variable to hardcode the hostname of the stubs
    setEnvVar "${stubRunnerName}" "APPLICATION_HOSTNAME" "${hostname}"
    setEnvVar "${stubRunnerName}" "APPLICATION_DOMAIN" "${domain}"
    local previousIfs="${IFS}"
    local listOfPorts=""
    local appGuid
    appGuid="$( "${CF_BIN}" curl "/v2/apps?q=name:${stubRunnerName}" -X GET | jq '.resources[0].metadata.guid' | sed 's/^"\(.*\)"$/\1/' )"
    echo "App GUID for ${stubRunnerName} is ${appGuid}"
    IFS="," read -ra vals <<< "${stubrunnerIds}"
    for stub in "${vals[@]}"; do
        echo "Parsing ${stub}"
        local port
        port=${stub##*:}
        if [[ "${listOfPorts}" == "" ]]; then
            listOfPorts="${port}"
        else
            listOfPorts="${listOfPorts},${port}"
        fi
    done
    echo "List of added ports: [${listOfPorts}]"
    "${CF_BIN}" curl "/v2/apps/${appGuid}" -X PUT -d "{\"ports\":[8080,${listOfPorts}]}"
    echo "Successfully updated the list of ports for [${stubRunnerName}]"
    IFS="," read -ra vals <<< "${stubrunnerIds}"
    for stub in "${vals[@]}"; do
        echo "Parsing ${stub}"
        local port
        port=${stub##*:}
        local newHostname="${hostname}-${port}"
        echo "Creating route with hostname [${newHostname}]"
        "${CF_BIN}" create-route "${testSpace}" "${domain}" --hostname "${newHostname}"
        local routeGuid
        routeGuid="$( "${CF_BIN}" curl -X GET "/v2/routes?q=host:${newHostname}" | jq '.resources[0].metadata.guid' | sed 's/^"\(.*\)"$/\1/' )"
        echo "GUID of the new route is [${routeGuid}]. Will update the mapping for port [${port}]"
        "${CF_BIN}" curl "/v2/route_mappings" -X POST -d "{ \"app_guid\": \"${appGuid}\", \"route_guid\": \"${routeGuid}\", \"app_port\": ${port} }"
        echo "Successfully updated the new route mapping for port [${port}]"
    done
    IFS="${previousIfs}"
} # }}}
```

Comment: Thanks, will read those resources! Never looked much into Spring Pipelines because I don't think that at the moment we'll have a chance to use it. Although I have some questions in my sleeve regarding that project, out of curiosity, mainly, but don't want to overflow the www with my questions :)

Comment: Is it possible to expose contracts over HTTP to the consumer. Our PCF currently does not support multiple ports, so we cannot use a central Stub Runner Server. Hence as a workaround, i would like to expose the behaviour of Stub runner with the actual Producer app over HTTP. Can you point me to code which is responsible for taking request and verifying with contract. Thanks.

Comment: Everything is possible ;) you could attach it as static sources. You could also resolve this contracts at runtime (just download a raw jar, unzip it and take the contracts). Another option is to apply the logic presented above to allow multiple port binding.